# Fazer um inputQuery substituir uma variavel no word se a condição for verdadeira

Tags: delphi

Estou trabalhando com o delphi e preciso de um método que faça o seguinte 
no documento do word aberto procure por uma variável '@Nome' se ele encontrar a variável '@Nome' abra um inputQuery para o usuário digitar o novo valor da variável e depois substitua o '@Nome' pelo valor digitado no InputQuery.

obs: a parte da substituição já tenho conhecimento o meu problema esta mesmo na parte do algoritmo percorrer o documento e caso ele encontre a variável retorne o inputQuery caso não encontre apenas continue executando o resto do código.

```
Begin
if Doc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText := '@Ref') then
  InputQuery('Nome Funcionario', 'Insira um Valor:', ref);
  Doc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText := '@Ref', ReplaceWith := ref);
end;
```

Comment: Eu colocaria o conteúdo de texto em um Memo, faria um laço de repetição para percorrer cada caractere e, quando encontrasse o '@', armazenaria os caracteres seguintes até o próximo 'espaço' e faria a substituição. Após todo o processo concluído, salvaria o conteúdo do Memo em um arquivo .doc.

Comment: Se colocar a lógica já existente (código) ficaria mais fácil do pessoal daqui te ajudar.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, mas já descobri como funciona e deu certo irei editar a publicação com o código para melhor entendimento